# How to make a Content View a Generic?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm tring to create a contet view (with code behind) generic.

I tried the basic, put the  on the class but this make the `InitializeComponent` not working, and apparently, the `partial` of the class doesn't are used anymore.

```
public partial class MockClass<T> : ContentView
    {

       public static readonly BindableProperty OptionsProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Options),
                typeof(List<T>),
                typeof(MockClass<>),
                null);
        public List<T>Options
        {
            get { return (List<T>)GetValue(OptionsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OptionsProperty, value); }
        }        

        public ChoiceComponentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
//The name "InitializeComponent" does not exist in the current context
//Cannot resolve the symbol "InitializeComponent" "
        }
    }
```

I belive that a need do something on the xaml file, but I did not find anything about.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you trying to display that you need your ContentView to be generic? Your ContentView should be consuming the data that you pass through, so I would recommend you convert your data into some standard type to display rather than making a Generic ContentView. You may have also seen this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1580) that relates directly to your issue.

Comment: The ideia was create a checkbox page, where the T is not necessary string, but be some object or anything else. Actually I am using just as IList, but in determined moment I have to check is the options is null, and if so, create a list. If this class was generic, problem solved. For now, in this case I create `List<object>`, but I have some issues with the validation type on the main form.

Comment: Based on that information, you wouldn't need a generic ContentView then, you would need to override the checkbox class to take a generic type I believe. If it isn't possible to override that class, you'd have to make your own.

Comment: Yes, but my Checkbox class is the ContentView, so, that's the problem :/

Comment: Is that all of your code? I'm not seeing the Checkbox class.

Comment: No, that's not all code, I just post the necessary to example my doubt. Basics have one more list to handle the selected options and the construction of the checkbox on the xaml.

Comment: I believe [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106919/inheritance-from-generic-pages) is the answer to your issue. From what I can tell, what you're trying to do simply isn't possible.

Comment: I've already seen that and not help me, at list, as I have imagined. Anyway, thanks for your help.